# Accessing a list as the key for a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to access a dictionary if the player tries to pick up the item, but I want the name to be flexible, for example:

```
items = {
['potion 1', 'clear potion', 'stinky potion']: potion1,
['key', 'old key', 'rusty key']: key,
['pineapple']: pineapple
}
```

I am trying to search through all of the keys in items, and if the input matches one of them then it will find where it is and call the variable for its information. I want it to print something like this:

```
>>>take potion
clear potion taken.
>>>inventory
inventory:
clear potion: a potion in a glass bottle. it smells really bad.
key: an old key.
```

I have just recently started coding so please explain how your solution works and how I can replicate it.

I have tried searching for the name in the list in the dictionary, but that only returns `True` or `False`. Currently I have:

```
def take(act, allitem, pos, posinv, inv):
  act = list(act.split(" "))
  end = False
  for item in act:
    if item in allitem:
      if item in posinv[pos]:
        inv.append(item)
        posinv[pos].remove(item)
        print(item.capitalize()+" taken.")
      else:
        print("I don't see a "+item+" here!")
```

This loops through the words in the prompt (`act`) and if one of them is an item then it checks if it is in the location and if it is it takes it from the location and adds it to the player's inventory. Otherwise it prints, `I don't see a ~example item~ here!`

I want the code to call the variable as it contains important information (weight, description, etc) that it needs when picking up the items but I can't figure out how (It might just be that I have very little experience coding and I'm not the best at googling)

Comment: Your dict is invalid. Lists, being modifiable and thus unhashable, can not be dict keys. Are those tuples instead?

Comment: Splitting your `act` by spaces will separate more than you desire. For example, if the user inputs `take potion 1`, `act` will become `['take', 'potion', '1']` and you will check for `potion` and `1` separately rather than `potion 1` as desired.

Comment: Instead of using a list as the key, just use multiple keys with the same value. `{'potion 1': potion1, 'clear potion': potion1, ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't use a list as a dictionary key. However, you can have multiple keys that map to the same object. For example,

```
items = {
   'potion 1': potion1,
   'clear potion': potion1,
   'stinky potion': potion1,
   'key': key,
   'old key': key,
   'rusty key': key,
   'pineapple': pineapple
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this at the time. This helps a lot!